# Assume $a_n$ is a positive sequence, and $ (1-\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}})n \rightarrow a>1 $. Prove $a_n$ converges to 0.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have tried every technique I know; I can't solve this question, so I assume it's an algebraic trick. Any ideas?

Edit: [The question was written incorrectly, $a_n$ is supposed to be the divisor.]

Comment: Are you sure the assumptions are correctly stated? The current version of your statement implies that $a_n$ is eventually strictly increasing. (To see this, notice that $1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ must be eventually positive.) So there is no chance your sequence converges to $0$. Rather, one can prove sort of the opposite: $a_n$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Look at the sequence $a_n=2(n-1)$ then your given expression converges to 2. But $a_n$ obviously goes to infinity.

Comment: @José: I wonder why you approved the last edit. The TeX is broken,  and the  fraction (which was originally $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$) is reversed, so that an answer is invalidated.

Comment: This seems like the [Raabe test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test) of series, where the sign of the terms got reversed.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was supposed to be $a_n$ at the bottom, the Latex confused me.

Comment: Can you edit the title to the right equation? Or right it here fully and correct? It is hard to understand the question right now

Comment: I tried to change it, but somebody changed it back. Apparently you can't edit the question if it invalidates an otherwise correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $a_n \to \infty$!. There exist $b>1$ and $n_0$ such that  $1-\frac {a_n} {a_{n+1}} >\frac b n$ for $n \geq n_0$. This gives $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} >c_n$ where $c_n=\frac 1 {1-\frac b n}$. Iterating this gives $a_{n+n_0} >a_{n_0} \prod_{k=n_0}^{n+n_0} c_k$. Hence it is enough to show that $\prod_{k=n_0}^{\infty} c_k=\infty$. Equivalently we have to show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \log (c_k)= \infty$. This follows from the divergence of harmonic series and the fact that $\log(1-x)$ behaves like $x$ for $x$ near $0$.